# SQL Query for Consolidation

Tags: sql, sql-server, consolidation

I need a little help...

I have two data tables:

Table of programmed circuits (theorical Itinerary)
[image]
Table of circuits covered by the sellers (Real Itinerary)
[image]
The result to be achieved:

[image]
Thanks...

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results in table form

Comment: For helping you we want to create and fill temporary tables. But we are not going to type over all your data, so please edit your question and provide the data as text, not as images

Comment: Look for `full join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select isnull(a.date, b.date), isnull(a.seller, b.seller), a.[theoretical itinerary], b.[real itinerary] 
from table1 a full join table2 b 
on a.date=b.date and a.seller=b.seller
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t.date, r.date) as date, coalesce(t.seller, r.seller) as seller,
       t.itinerary as theoretical_itinerary,
       r.itinerary as real_itinerary
from theoretical t full join
     real r
     on t.date = r.date and t.seller = r.seller;
```

The `coalesce()` is an unfortunate artifact of using `full join`.  If you don't include it, then you will see `NULL` values for the matching columns.  (If only SQL Server supported `using`, then there would be a simple alternative.)